# Application stopped

Tags: android

I am getting an error like your application has stopped unexpectedly. I have attached my logcat here. Please help me.

```
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myoverlays1/com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
08-06 10:18:00.226: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  ... 11 more
08-06 10:18:01.996: I/Process(868): Sending signal. PID: 868 SIG: 9
```

Comment: have u add mape.jar in u r build-path ? if u r using google api then just remove mape.jar form build-path it may help..

Comment: I am beginner in android so please tell me where to find that jar file

Comment: first click on u r project folder then Project->Properties->Libraries

Answer (score 3):

If `MyOverlays` is your own class file means, Did you properly declared the `MyOverlays` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Like below -

```
<activity android:name=".MyOverlays"></activity>
```

Otherwise, if it is class file from any external `.jar` file means, Did you import it properly,

- Create a `libs` folder in your project. And, copy the required `.jar` file in there.
- Import it properly using (project -> properties -> java build path -> Add jars/Add external jars -> select jar file)

Hope this helps you.

**Edit**

I hope that your `MyOverlays` is a class file that is working for `MapView` for this, you've to declare this class in your manifest file as -

```
<activity android:name="com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays"></activity>
```

and, check there your maps library declared or not

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside of your `<application>` tag.

Comment: Ya my class name is given properly in AndroidManifest.xml file, but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Post some code of `MyOverlays` class and your manifest file. And, Just try to declare your `MyOverlays` as `com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays` in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

you use external lib you give reference but you set tick in property of that project to resolve that error

or you use myoverlay in xml that not get reference

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `com.example.myoverlays1.MyOverlays` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: r u using Google API for for your App.?

Answer (score 0):

Please check all activities are declared in Android Manfiest.xml. It looks like MyOverlays class is not declared in AndroidManfiest.xml